# C# how to show available data one by one in textbox

Tags: c#

Hi I am using HtmlAgilityPack to scrap some data from web using c# . Here is the code :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var url = this.textBox1.Text;
        var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
        var document = webGet.Load(url);

        var metaTags = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//meta");
        if (metaTags != null)
        {
            foreach (var tag in metaTags)
            {
                var name = tag.Attributes["name"].Value;
                var content = tag.Attributes["content"].Value;

                this.textBox2.Text = name + " : " + content;
            }
        }
    }
```

its getting a link from textbox1 and showing the output to textbox2 . Its showing the last available data . I can concate the available data but it will show all data at once. Actually I want to show one data when it is available while others are being processed so that user can realize the scrapping progress.Would anyone please help ??

Comment: Do you mean `textBox2` only shows the last `name : content`, but you want to show them one at a time with a delay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the first half of your code is correct, this *will* show the data one-by-one.  Most likely, the `foreach` loop is executing too quickly for you to notice the "one-by-one" effect.

You could apply an artificial delay if you need to display each result long enough for someone to read.  Maybe with a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) or something similar.

An alternative is to use a multi-line textbox (for example a [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx)) and place each result on a new-line. Or a [ComboBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.aspx), which won't take up as much room.  These options allow you to keep the data, without having to overwrite it.

Comment: Thread.Sleep(1000); is not working . when i use "this.textBox2.Text = name + " : " + content + "\r\n"; its overwriting the previous textbox2 data . that's not what i want .

Comment: @qmaruf If you don't want to overwrite, you will have to use `this.textBox2.Text = this.textBox2.Text + name + ":" + content;`.  You are reassigning the value of `this.textBox2.Text` every time you use the `=` sign.
Also, what is the problem with `Thread.Sleep()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can user Timer control to delay the display of next value in the loop.

You can also use BackgroundWorker to get this done. However this would add complexity to your code. Please look at [Beginners Guide to Threading in .NET: Part 5](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/ThreadingDohttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578725/c-sharp-how-to-show-available-data-one-by-one-in-textboxtNet5.aspx)

Or you can use Thread.Sleep(xx) which will delay the execution for the milliseconds you specify.

```
  Thread.Sleep(2000);
  this.textBox2.Text += name + " : " + content + Environment.NewLine;
```

Comment: isn't there any easy way to do this ??

Comment: Use thread.sleep which will delay the execution of current thread for the milliseconds you specify. please check the updated answer.

Comment: Thread.sleep(XX) is just delaying the final output . All data are being displayed together at a time .

Comment: Can you post the code where you are using Thread.Sleep call? I believe it is being done on a wrong place.

Comment: I want something like this : http://i51.tinypic.com/2wc2s9k.png . data should be displayed one by one

Comment: I do understand what you are trying to achieve. However if you want to do it in the right way then go through the Link I have mentioned in my answer. I believe if you would have gone through that link you would have completed the work by now. Anyway Can you share the code you have written so far (including Thread.Sleep call).

Comment: this code is appending all data in textbox2 and after that its showing them all together . let there are thousands of data . i want to show a data when it is available , while others are being processed .here is the code : http://paste.ubuntu.com/777267/

Comment: In you case Thread.Sleep will not work. It will delay the execution of UI thread. You would have to use the BackGroundWorked to achieve what you want.